# How to insert or update record into database using apache solr?

Tags: database, solr, insert, record

1. How to insert data in DB2 database using apache solr, so that there is no need to use delta query?
2. Also can we split concatenated string field into different fields which we can use for searching and indexing?

Comment: Ask separate questions separately, and provide information about what you've tried and what fails, and give enough detail so it's at least possible to answer in a sensible way.

Answer (score 0):

1. The Data Import Handler (DIH) provides a mechanism for importing content from a RDBMS and indexing it. You could refer to this wiki page [DataImportHandler](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler)
2. To split a concatenated field into different fields during Indexing, use the Transformer component mentioned in the above wiki. Transformers manipulate the fields in a document returned by an entity. A transformer can create new fields or modify existing ones.